# Performance in multithreaded Json.NET serialization

Tags: json, multithreading, json.net

We're deserializing large JSON payloads from an external API, each response being roughly 30MB.

On my developer machine it takes 0.3s to call `JsonConvert.DeserializObject(jsonString)` with those 30MB in a single thread. But if I deserialize in multiple threads the time spent per deserialization drastically increases as the number of threads increases, up to 5-10s sometimes. My test code looks like this:

```cs
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("c:/largejson.json");

var count = 100;
var ops = 0;
var results = new ConcurrentBag<TimeSpan>();

while (ops < count)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopwatch.Start();

                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                ops++;

                stopwatch.Stop();
                results.Add(stopwatch.Elapsed);
            }
        ));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

var totalSeconds = results.Sum(r => r.TotalSeconds);
var secondsPerOp = totalSeconds / ops;
```

And here's the file I'm using: https://github.com/andersekdahl/files/blob/master/largejson.json

I've tested both with and without passing in a `new JsonSerializerSettings()` as a second argument but it doesn't make any difference.

My first instinct was that there was some locking inside Json.NET but when I profiled it using dotTrace nothing really sticks out. A lot of time is spent in `JTokenWriter.WritePropertyName` but that doesn't look like it's shared between threads/deserializations.

Anyone has any clues what's causing the slowdown?

Comment: As an aside, you should deserialize large JSON directly from a stream rather than loading from a string and deserializing the string.  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#MemoryUsage.  That's obviously not the problem here though.

Comment: When deserializing to `dynamic` you are really parsing to `JToken`.  I.e. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)` is equivalent to `JToken.Parse(json, new JsonLoadSettings { LineInfoHandling = LineInfoHandling.Ignore })`.  Does the problem still reproduce if you use the latter?  If so that would eliminate the possibility that locks in the contract resolver are causing your problem.

Comment: Interesting, JToken.Parse is about as fast as JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() on a single thread, but quite a lot faster with multiple threads. Both deserializes in 0.3s on one thread, but JToken.Parse takes around 1.5s with 10 threads and JsonConvert.DeserializeObject (still to JToken) takes 2.5. Unfortunately the real scenario isn't just doing JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() but has custom converters etc. Deserializing into a JToken was just my way of getting a bare bones test case as it only uses Json.NET and none of our custom converters.

Comment: Interesting.  If you need to deserialize to a typed model, what happens if you use a thread static contract resolver, e.g. as shown [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NkuxzB)?